# Same code for client and server

Tags: javascript, web-applications

Is it feasible to have parts of the code shared between webapp's client and server? Assuming I use a javascript-based server, I hope I could have at least form verification code and parts of logic shared.

I worry about incompatibilities between javascript engines, though.

Comment: If you develop a client-side Javascript code you already have to take care of different Javascript engines, right? So adding a server-side one, justs adds another one, making `N + 1` instead of `N`. So I wouldn't worry about incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If your code runs on Chrome (V8), it will also run under [Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info) (V8) which today, is the #1 choice for server side JavaScript.

Of course you need to make sure that you don't use any Chrome specific stuff, but the same hold true for things that only work Firefox (like **noSuchMethod**) etc.

But I can't think of any particular things when it comes to form validation that would break cross engine compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

http://jaxer.org/ has some really nice looking examples for sharing code between client and server, as well as manipulating the DOM in both locations.  However, this project looks like it may have been abandoned by its creator.  Just posting the link because the design concepts might be useful to you when trying to share validation code in both locations.

Comment: note that the jaxer.org no longer points to that project's website, so I presume that the project has been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Engine incompatibility should not extend to data-validation, it should be limited to DOM interaction.

If your javascript engines are so weirdly different that they treat strings and integers and whatnot differently -- stop using them.